# asp.net WebControl event order and ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom class creating a dropdownlist control as below:

```
public class IHGridView : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
{
    private string _dataSource = "not set yet";

    public string DataSource
    {
        get { return _dataSource; }
        set { _dataSource = value; }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // VIewState is alive. When I select an option and submit, after postback it's selected value is the one I selected.
        this.Controls.Add(_dropDownList);
    }
```

or

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        // VIewState is dead. When I select an option and submit, after postback it's selected value is the default one.
        this.Controls.Add(_dropDownList);
    }
```

So, now I come up with the result that I have to add control in "OnInit" void.
But, this "OnInit" is the first void that this class writes.
If I want to use a property like "DataSource" before, "OnInit" void...
How would I do that?

EDIT:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IHGridViewTest2.DataSource = "fired";
    }
```

DataSource is set when the button in aspx page is fired.

Comment: when a button is fired. I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to add _dropDownList twice? once in the OnInit should be enough, and OnInit is where it should be added if you want it in the control collection - thus having viewstate persisted and restored.

to access and bind _dropDownList for example, override the DataBind method - at which point all the properties will be available to you.

```
protected override void DataBind(){
    base.DataBind();
    _dropDownList.DataSource = this.DataSource;
    _dropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

this is pseudo code, and has not been tested or validated

EDIT:

Call overriden DataBind method

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IHGridViewTest2.DataSource = "fired";
    IHGridViewTest2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: There is "OR" in my source codes. Maybe you didn't read my question carefully. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Question was edited, but my answer still applies, maintain the control being added on OnInit, then override the DataBind method as above, just modify you're code on the button handler to: